# Twitterizer Follow Users with Stream

Tags: twitter, twitterizer

I'm currrently using the Twitterizer Framework to track many keywords (the limit is 400 from the Twitter API). Therefore, i try to follow some users (their timelines) but I get the Error "NotAcceptable".

Example Code A(this works):

```
StreamOptions options = new StreamOptions();
options.Track.Add("keyword 1");
options.Track.Add("keyword 2");
...
```

Example Code B(this works):

```
StreamOptions options = new StreamOptions();
options.Follow.Add("ID1");
options.Follow.Add("ID2");
...
```

Here I get the Error "NotAcceptable".
What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this will be because of the type of stream you are starting.  Right after the code you posted, you should have code to *start* your stream:

```
stream.StartPublicStream(...);
```

My guess is you actually have *StartUserStream* in error ...